# wrong output while making palindrome checker in assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm64, palindrome

I am trying to make a palindrome checker but it keeps saying its not a palindrome when it is. I got the string and loaded it into a stack (as a part of my school assignment) and so now my program checks the outer pairs of the string to see if theyre the same.

```
endOfString:
mov x4, #2
sdiv X2, X2, X4 // divide x2 by 2 --> it is how many times we need to check the two outer pairs of the string
MOV X3, #0 // counter      
LDR X0, =output
LDR x5, =input      

compareChar:
LDRB W1, [SP], #16  // pop characters from the stack 
LDRB W2, [X5], #1 //load byte data from X5 and put it into W2, increment by 1
CMP W1, W2 // check the pair
B.NE Palno // is not a palindrome
B.EQ pal // it is a palindrome
ADD X3, X3, #1        
CMP X3, X2              
B.LE compareChar
```

Comment: I don't see any `ldrb` 8-bit loads, only 32-bit loads.  (And stores?  Why are you storing anything?  Is it checking for a palindrome as it copies the string somewhere else?)  Also, use `lsr` (`x>>1`) to divide by 2, not `sdiv`.  Or better, just start with pointers to the ends, and keep looping inward until they cross; that's the standard algorithm.  Your current code increments SP by 16, X0 by 1, and X5 by 1 every iteration.  Nothing scanning backwards.

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to work in 4-byte chunks, comparing 4 bytes at a time (for strings at least 4 bytes long), you'd use `rev32 w2, w2` (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2020-12/Base-Instructions/REV32--Reverse-bytes-in-32-bit-words-) before the compare, and offsets of `#4` and `#-4`.  BTW, you need to keep the stack aligned by 16, so you'll need a different pointer for it unless you want to use ASIMD vector registers to compare 16 bytes at a time, or a pair of 8-byte registers with `ldp` and 2x `rev64`.

Comment: how do i grab the first element of the stack and increment it upwards?

Comment: Copy SP to another register ahead of the loop, so you can use `ldrb w1, [x6], #1` or something.